# How to get access to view that is located outside of FrameLayout of TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

When an Activity X is loaded into FrameLayout when tab is changed I want that X to be able access to `tmp` LinearLayout that is located outside of TabHost. 
Assume that TmpActivity is loaded into FrameLayout when some tab was clicked, so in that activity I want do something like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tmp);            
    }
```

How I can do this?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tmp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:background="#00FF00">               
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabHost 
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500px"
                    android:padding="5dp" 
                    android:background="#FF0000"/>
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="#FF00FF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your parent activity from your activity loaded in your tab host frame layout. From there, you can access your linear layout throught a getter or a member variable located in your TabHostActivity.